# Create separate distplot from countplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I create distplot from countplot

```
plt.rcdefaults()
%config InlineBackend.figure_format='retina'

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
ax = sns.countplot(x='Age',hue='Gender',data=df,edgecolor="None")
ax.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

for rect in ax.patches:
        x = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.
        y = rect.get_height()
        try:
            ax.annotate("{}".format(int(y)), (x,y), ha='center', va='bottom', clip_on=True)
        except:
            pass

ax.set_xlabel('Age', color='green')
ax.set_ylabel('Count', color='green')
ax.set_title('Countplot for Age(Gender)', color='tomato',weight='bold')

plt.legend(title='Gender', fontsize='large', loc='upper right').get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('files\\Countplot_for_Age(Gender).jpg')
```

[image]

I want distplot for 2 Genders either in same plot or separately

Any suggestions or help will be highly appreciable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The x-axis of a `countplot` is categorical: it puts one bar for each encountered age, skipping bars when there are no rows for a certain age (21 and 23 in the example). Internally the bars are numbered as 0, 1, 2, ...
The y-axis is the count, which is proportional to the number of rows.

For a `distplot`, the x-axis are the ages themselves, and the y-axis is a probability distribution, which usually are quite small numbers (the area under the curve is normalized to be 1).

So, as both the x-axis and the y-axis are different, it is better to use separate subplots.

A `distplot` can be generated directly from the given data. Passing the same `ax` results in two `distplot`s in the same subplot. A `distplot` is a combination of a histogram and a `kdeplot`. If the histogram isn't needed,  `hist=False` leaves
it out, or the `kdeplot` can be called directly. The `shade=True` option adds shading to the plot.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

NF = 50
NM = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.concatenate([np.random.randint(13, 20, NF) + np.random.randint(2, 7, NF),
                                          np.random.randint(15, 23, NM)]),
                   'Gender': np.repeat(['female', 'male'], (NF, NM))})
df['Age'] = df['Age'].where((df['Age'] != 21) & (df['Age'] != 23), 20)

sns.set_style('darkgrid')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(12, 4))

ax = sns.countplot(x='Age', hue='Gender', data=df, edgecolor="None", ax=axs[0])
ax.tick_params(bottom=False, left=False)
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

for rect in ax.patches:
    x = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2.
    y = rect.get_height()
    ax.annotate(f"{y:.0f}", (x, y), ha='center', va='bottom', clip_on=True)

ax.set_xlabel('Age', color='green')
ax.set_ylabel('Count', color='green')
ax.set_title('Countplot for Age(Gender)', color='tomato', weight='bold')
ax.legend(title='Gender', fontsize='large', loc='upper right').get_frame().set_facecolor('white')

for gender in ('female', 'male'):
    # ax2 = sns.kdeplot(df[df['Gender'] == gender]['Age'], shade=True, ax=axs[1], label=gender)
    ax2 = sns.distplot(df[df['Gender'] == gender]['Age'], hist=False, kde_kws={'shade': True}, ax=axs[1], label=gender)

ax2.set_axisbelow(True)
ax2.set_xlabel('Age', color='green')
ax2.set_ylabel('probability distribution', color='green')
ax2.set_title('Distplot for Age(Gender)', color='tomato', weight='bold')
ax2.legend(title='Gender', fontsize='large', loc='upper right').get_frame().set_facecolor('white')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Thanks buddy! Also I would like to ask is there any way to shade(fill) the curve under it with respective colours?